# Rails - Does this Rails method acquire a lock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say there's no connections available in the connection pool, and I'm doing this

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
...
end
```

Will this method acquire a lock and only continue when some connection has been released?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if no connection is available in the pool this method will wait until a connection is free to run it. Default timeout for wait is 5 seconds which can be changed. Follow the link below for more information.

Reference:

[Connection Pool Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html)

Comment: I have one more question, please. If I do a find() inside this method, but I only use it later (after the "end"), will it actually perform the query on the DB after the "end" using lazy fetch? or will it use it in a controlled way like this method suggests? Because in that case I'd need to wrap my whole method with this method, or use eager fetch, right?

Comment: My understanding is, Rails will lazy fetch the values after the "end" when you need them using connection pool. I am not too sure about this, but you can quickly test it out in Rails console and check the functionality. :)